# Understanding Ports

Tags: networking, ip, port, smb

Total laymen trying to get a grasp on my home network.  I have noticed that my sons laptop is consistently running with port 445 "SMB directly over IP" and was wondering if someone could tell me if that means he is in a chat room or communicating with someone off of his laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean he's "running with port 445"?  Where/how are you seeing this information?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what that means........ Is that something fairly easy to do? I am only looking through Fing..

Comment: I'm seeing the information on Fing

Comment: Port 445 is a normal port to have open and see ocasional traffic on, especially for Windows computers.  It is the port that is used by Windows File & Printer sharing.

Comment: Check this out for the "standard" protocols used by certain TCP/IP port numbers... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers... For SMB, that is likely talking with some SHARED folder or SHARED printer i.e. `\\ipaddress\sharename` or `\\ipaddress\sharedprinter`.

Comment: -1: [Google Port 445](https://www.google.ca/search?q=port+445) and do a little reading my friend. https://www.grc.com/port_445.htm, http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=445, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports, http://windowsitpro.com/networking/whats-port-445-used-windows-2000-and-later-versions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block

Comment: Thank You all for weighing in! I really appreciate it........ I've been looking for a site like this for a long time!

Comment: your question is kind of untechnical.. You are getting some useful responses in comment but another site you could try is www.sevenforums.com   or if you google the reuivalent for other windows versions e.g. google sevenforums windows 8 or sevenforums windows 10, you get http://www.eightforums.com/    and http://www.tenforums.com/

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses *port 445* to access or give access to local shares (folders, printers, resources), it is used for a service called *Server Message Block (SMB)*.